# Error in escaping string for highlighting function (js -regexp)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to implement a highlighting function and here is what i have so far

```
function highlight(value, term){
    return value.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + 
      term.replace(/([\^\$\(\)\[\]\{\}\*\.\+\?\|\\])/i, "\\$1") + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "i"), "<strong>$1</strong>")
  }
```

For the most part it works, but the code breaks when the term contains a ')' and this error is raised: SyntaxError: unmatched ) in regular expression. It appears that ')' is not escaped by:

```
term.replace(/([\^\$\(\)\[\]\{\}\*\.\+\?\|\\])/i, "\\$1")
```

However I look at my that code though, I can't seem to find where the error is. Can you help point it out?? Or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think you should use double backslashes (\\ instead of \ ). term.replace(/([\\^\\$\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\\*\\.\\+\\?\\|\\])/i, "\\$1")

Comment: it only caused syntactical error

Comment: term.replace(new RegExp("[/\\[\\^\\$\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\\*\\.\\+\\?\\|\\]]", "gi"),"\\$1");

Answer (score 0):

Your `term.replace` code only replaces the *first* instance of any of the terms found.  You need to use `g` at the end of the regex.  It's also not necessary to capture since you can just use the expression itself (and I have removed some unnecessary escapes):

```
term.replace(/[\^$()[\]{}*.+?|\\\\]/g, "\\$&")
```

A more complete version is here: http://phpjs.org/functions/preg_quote/

Comment: the omission of g was intentional

Comment: @WataTakaheshi why is that?

Comment: and again, this did not solve the problem as doing as you said and calling highlight('abc(d)', 'abc(') returned 'abc(d)' instead of '<strong>abc(</strong>d)'